# 30 days LeetCode April Challenge Day 1 - Single Number

Tags: python

Am new to coding challenges,am trying to solve a coding challenge on leetCode. 
Can anybody help me understand the problem clearly to code in python.
What you mean by **Without using extra memory**?

**Problem**
Given a non-empty array of integers, every element appears twice except for one. Find that single one.

**Note:**

Your algorithm should have a linear runtime complexity. Could you implement it without using extra memory?

**Example 1**

```
Input: [2,2,1]
Output: 1
```

**Example 2**

```
Input: [4,1,2,1,2]
Output: 4
```

Comment: "Without using extra memory" means they don't want you to use any variable-sized storage other than the input array.  You can only use scalar variables, i.e., constant-sized storage.

Comment: Got it,thank you, can u please elaborate the problem.

Comment: They should have phrased it as "using an amount of memory independent of the input size".

Comment: @AdityaNikhil You should report the problem as text. Otherwise, if/when the link will get broken, this question will be useless to future reader.

Comment: Thanks Tom, if time persists, i request you to go through the problem and discuss it here,it'll be really helpful!

Comment: @AdityaNikhil See Nam's answer, that's the correct solution, and it's very simple once you see how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve this problem without extra memory by using the `XOR` operator. The XOR logical operation, or exclusive or, takes two boolean operands and returns true if and only if the operands are different. 
There are 2 properties of the XOR operator:

- XOR of a number with itself is 0.
- XOR of a number with 0 is number itself.

So, for example, when you do 2 ^ 2, the result will be 0 (0010 ^ 0010 = 0000), if you do 2 ^ 0, then the result will be 2 (0010 ^ 0000). As the problem stated, there is only one number appears once and every other appears twice, then when doing this operation, those identical will eliminate each other and give us the final number that appears once.

Here is the simple solution in Python which do it in-place (in-place means that you don't have to create auxiliary data structure to solve the problem):

```py
def find_12_xor(items):
    result = 0
    for item in items:
        result ^= item
    return result
```

Comment: Yeah, just because on LeetCode they already defined a Class that wraps this function.

Comment: Oh, I see - I didn't realize that.

Comment: Thanks alot Nam for this clear explanation!
And thanks norok for turning the code to python.

Comment: @AdityaNikhil it was already converted to Python by Nam V. Do, I just polished a little bit not to look like Java translation :-P